# Help computing the volume integral for the body $|z| \leq \sqrt{3-x^2}\sqrt{3-y^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm currently studying volume integrals and am stuck with an old exam task.

The task is to calculate the volume of the following object:

$$|z| \leq \sqrt{3-x^2}\sqrt{3-y^2}$$

I know that the square root must be greater than zero to have a real solution, thus:

1.$$ \sqrt{3-x^2} \geq 0 \Leftrightarrow 3-x^2 \geq0 \Rightarrow |x| \leq \sqrt3$$

2.$$ \sqrt{3-y^2} \geq 0 \Leftrightarrow 3-y^2 \geq0 \Rightarrow |y| \leq \sqrt3$$

The right part of the inequation $|z| \leq \sqrt{3-x^2}\sqrt{3-y^2}$  has its maximum when $x$ and $y$ become zero.

This leads to: $ |z|\leq \sqrt3\sqrt3 \Leftrightarrow |z|\leq 3$.

My problem is, i don't quite understand how to set the limits of the tripple integral right to compute the volume or is maybe my following, naive solution right?

$$\int_K dxdydz = \int_ {-\sqrt3}^{\sqrt3}\int_{-\sqrt3}^{\sqrt3} \int_{-\sqrt{3-x^2}\sqrt{3-y^2}}^{\sqrt{3-x^2}\sqrt{3-y^2}} dzdydx = \int_ {-\sqrt3}^{\sqrt3}\int_{-\sqrt3}^{\sqrt3}2\sqrt{3-x^2}\sqrt{3-y^2} dydx =9\pi^2/2$$

Is there a more elegant solution, maybe via substitution with cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: Your method is correct and Idon't think there is a simpler one.

Comment: Your solution method seems fine. Cylindrical coordinates will not be of much help while integrating over squares.

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys, i appreciate it.